# How to Perform Force Alignment on Windows without WSL or Cygwin? Python Module Recommendations Appreciated

Tags: python, windows, alignment, audio-processing

I'm currently working on a project that involves Force Alignment, and I'm looking for a way to accomplish this on Windows without resorting to tools like Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) or Cygwin. I've found these tools to be quite helpful, but I'm interested in exploring potential alternatives that are more Windows-native.

Additionally, if there are any Python modules that can aid in achieving Force Alignment, it would be greatly appreciated if you could suggest them. My goal is to streamline the process and make it more accessible for Windows users who may not be familiar with WSL or Cygwin.

Any insights, recommendations, or guidance on how to achieve Force Alignment on Windows, especially through Python modules, will be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance for your assistance!